# Define default content when developer drags the control from toolbar

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I create custom control and is work fine but I wish that when developer drags it from toolbar by default content value will be `<my:controlcustom><Grid></Grid></my:controlcustom>` 
or other controls by default. How I cant do that?